# NSURLSession redirect not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, redirect, nsurlsession

So i have this URL i am trying to get data from. However it redirects me a couple of times. As far as i know i can follow redirects by setting the delegate of the session and implementing the following method:

```
- (void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session
task:(NSURLSessionTask *)task
willPerformHTTPRedirection:(NSHTTPURLResponse *)response
newRequest:(NSURLRequest *)request
completionHandler:(void (^)(NSURLRequest *))completionHandler{
    completionHandler(request);
}
```

Following the documentation: calling the complementationHandler method with the request as parameter should allow me to do a redirect.

Well it works.. but it only works once. The second time i also receive a response with status code 303 but this one does not get redirected. It skips the redirect and goes straight to my own "final" completionHandler.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Same session?  If so, assuming it is a GET request, the results are probably getting served from the cache.

If it isn't the same session, you probably didn't set the delegate on it.